# Core Data fetch sum by days

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have specific but quite common task for Core Data, which answer can't find.
Assume, that we have CoreData model for income. Every day it filled with unknown number of records. 
The task is to display plot of incomes by some period of time.
So, what I must to do is calculate total income for day and display the plot.

I know how to sum for period of time:

```
NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"income"];
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:" arguments:@[keyPathExpression]];

NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[expressionDescription setName:@"result"];
[expressionDescription setExpression:expression];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDoubleAttributeType];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = <#create fetch request#>;
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:@[expressionDescription]];
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date >= %@ && date <= %@", startDate, endDate,];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

If I make NSCompoundPredicate it just sum all the fields and response contain one sum.

How can I execute it for every period of time and get in once response?

Thanks

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the equivalent of a SQL 'GROUP BY' clause.  In CoreData you can do this by setting the `propertiesToGroupBy` property of the fetchRequest.  The problem is that `date` includes (presumably) the time, so each date/time will be grouped separately.  If you can amend your data structure to include a property for the day (excluding time), then you could use that to group the results.

Comment: @pbasdf I was wondering how to crunch strftime into SQL produced by CoreData. Like first we declare fetchedProperty that is strftime blah and then we group by this field. Not sure if expression will validate that. Example: http://aprogrammersday.blogspot.com/2014/02/group-by-month-or-year-and-sum-in-sqlite.html?m=1

Comment: @Andy I hadn't thought about Fetched Properties, but I can't see how they can be used to get strftime into the SQL?

Comment: @pbasdf wow actually might be interesting to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

A proven way to do this is to use the section feature of `NSFetchedResultsController`. You would have to somehow persist the day information for this to work, but there is some easy to follow sample code available by Apple.

Check out [Date Section Titles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html).

You would then use the `objects` method of the section info protocol to address the objects you want. With KVC, it is then very easy (and elegant) to compute the sum (without the involved expression syntax).

```
NSNumber *sum = [[sectionInfo objects] valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.income"];
```

In case you worry about efficiency - don't fret. This will work without lags on the main thread with close to 100.000s records. The fetched results controller will make sure in the background that both memory and CPU constraints are taken into account.

Comment: It's not CoreData solution. It's a pure loop.

Comment: Seems like a good argument to make the move to Core Data. :-)

Comment: Well I prefer proper solutions even if your loop wins on first 100k over CoreData.

Comment: Misunderstanding. I thought you are using and array and you are using a loop, you thought I was proposing a loop. No. KVC is not a loop. This is the recommended method - you can check this in the Core Data Programming Guide.

Comment: Didn't know that! Thanks :-) So there is some magic again! KVC on regular array would be a loop, but turns out whatever CoreData returns has some magic KVC. I am skeptical and I need to see if any SQL would be produced for that by CoreData.